# android avd manager not fetching anything from addons site

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am using eclipse and I tried to use the avd manager but it is not fetching anything from the repository.xml as well as addon.xml. I tried to use the avd manager outside eclipse too, but its all same. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVD Manager isn't used to fetch anything, you want the SDK Manager. First download the platforms you want with SDK Manager, and then you can create Android Virtual Devices (AVDs) with the AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are getting the exception: [Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/andr oid/repository/repository.xml](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/63a44163a8d07cd9?pli=1)

or else here is the Android documentation on Troubleshooting for the same:

**Problems connecting to the SDK repository:**

If you are using the SDK and AVD Manager to download components and are encountering connection problems, try connecting over http, rather than https. To switch the protocol used by the SDK and AVD Manager, follow these steps:

1. With the Android SDK and AVD Manager window open, select "Settings" in the left pane.
2. On the right, in the "Misc" section, check the checkbox labeled "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."
3. Click Save & Apply.